# TeXstudio not generating PDF file

Tags: texstudio

I have installed TeXstudio on Ubuntu machine. When I changed the engine to XeLaTeX, it doesn't generate the PDF file.

I tooked several minutes to find the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of paths in TeXstudio, although my answer has some details to Windows users, the configurations in TeXstudio is pretty much the same https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528433/140133

Answer (score 1):

After several minuets of Googling I finally found a fix from [latex.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31456).

> Open, Texstudio, goto options and click on it, click on configure Texstudio, click on build and view, then select pdf chain then click ok. I hope this will give you PDF output.

I think it's great to have this answer on Stack community.