# Unable to build and view pdf on TexMaker

Tags: errors

I just installed TexMaker on my laptop and was about to build and view pdf. But an error message jumped out:

"Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex".

I have tried to access "Options->Config TexMaker" and the PdfLaTex showed me
"pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex".

How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: That means that either you have not installed tex or it is not installed in the location the your editor expectss

Comment: this is very much a FAQ hopefully the answers here will help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Could+not+start+the+command.+pdflatex+-synctex%3D1+-interaction%3Dnonstopmode+%25.tex

Comment: Hi @Simon219 and welcome to TeX-SE. The most basic advice in this case is to install the editor (TeXmaker) **after** the manager (MikTeX, TeXlive).
If you install **before**, it will probably not find the `.exe`s files.
If you cannot do this (no permission, no time, etc) you may try to directly inform the path where `pdflatex.exe` is. Check [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528417/140133).